# Way of creating "fake" DEM data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I want to create a hypsometric map of a fictional island chain and I would like to know if there is a way of generation of a "fake" DEM data in order to have a basis for the map. I am not a coding expert so I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve that much coding.

Comment: Is the coordinate system of importance?

Comment: If you know some real place looking like the one you want you can download a free DEM, for example [ASTER](https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/news/new-aster-gdem) of that area

Comment: How much freedom do you need/want in the creating of the DEM? There are many techniques possible. You could also apply "noise" raster/image filters to alter existing DEMS in a GIS or photoshop/blender

Comment: Expanding what @Bera mentioned: free to use DEM is preinstalled in newer QGIS versions: in the browser panel, expand XYZ tiles and drag-and-drop Mapzen Global Terrain to the Layers panel, then download/export the extent and resolution you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if the GIS community is the right community to ask such questions as GIS normally does not involve creating artificial landscapes. I guess your question would be better asked in a 3D community, e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/ or  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Grass r.surf.fractal https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42241/2856

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be to start a project in a photoshop of sorts and "paint" a DEM there. I think this gives the most flexibility but less precision. As it is fictional I assume the CRS is not of importance.

The Pixel color value can be interpret as a height value if you export this image as a TIFF to be used in for example QGIS.